# How to get realtime updates for a subcollection in firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

My database contains a subcollection called 'watched', for videos watched. I'd like to be able to keep track such subcollection in real time. The path looks like this: `users/userDocument/watched/date/nestedObjectsForMoviesWatched`

e.g. `users/as7f9as98dfa/watched/June-2020/ 
       {name: Forrest Gump, watched: true} {name: Interstellar, watched: false}`

Here's how I try to handle it

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeWatched = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userId)
      .collection('watched')       //why doesn't this work?
      .doc(month)
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        //how to handle snapshot received?
      })

      return () => {
        unsubscribeWatched()
      }

  }, [])
```

It is specifically important that my app is aware of when changes are made to the `watched` property in a given object.

Comment: What doesn't work about the code you shared?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes) documentation can help you to perform the task you want. As you can see in the shared link, "If you want to receive snapshot events when the document or query metadata changes, pass a listen options object when attaching your listener". So, it is only necessary to add "includeMetadataChanges: true" in your code, as you can see below. The complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/f003ef8c725f0039215badc00f888c41620bb8d2/firestore/test.firestore.js#L640-L646).

```
useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribeWatched = firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('users')
  .doc(userId)
  .collection('watched') 
  .doc(month)
  .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    includeMetadataChanges: true
  })

  return () => {
    unsubscribeWatched()
  }}
```